# programmatically show or hide gridview bound fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to programmatically set some bound fields visibility inside a gridview.
does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it by,

```
    int colIndStudID = 1;
    int colIndUnitID = 2;

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[colIndStudID].Visible = false;
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[colIndUnitID].Visible = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow gv in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        gv.Cells[colIndStudID].Visible = false;
        gv.Cells[colIndUnitID].Visible = false;
    }
```

Go through [this](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2008/03/how-to-hide-gridview-columns-in-normal.html) link. Contains example exactly matching your requirement.

Hope Its helpful.

Comment: what is colindstudid? is that the column number from left to right starting at 0?

Comment: its not about left or right col, its just colid

Comment: Just go through link. Exact solution is there